# Hibernate : MS SQL 2012 Strange Behavior with hbm2ddl.auto=update

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am facing following problem in my application only if I use MS SQL

**Scope**

**Hibernate** : 5.2.8.Final

**MS SQL SERVER** : 2012

**JDBC Driver** : net.sourceforge.jtds 1.3.1

**Spring** : 4.3.7.RELEASE

**JAVA** : 1.8.0.121

**Problem**
When I use a fresh Schema for the application, all if the table and relations are created successfully. But if I add a new field in entity, Hibernate tries to run this kind of query on all tables

```
alter table A add constraint FKh20u37tju4rdvm3kmhve8fu8e foreign key (last_modified_by_id) references B
```

Which results to

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: There is already an object named 'FKh20u37tju4rdvm3kmhve8fu8e' in the database.
```

**Overall Impact**

None of the newly added fields gets added to the schema

I tried some suggestion like

1. Change Hibernate Version tried 5.2.5 to 5.2.8
2. Changed JDBC Driver to com.microsoft.sqlserver 6.1.0.jre8
3. Removing Connection Pool
4. Set ValidationQuery in Data source to SELECT 1
5. Move @Id field in entities instead of having it in @MappedSuperclass
6. Set Default Schema in Hibernate Config

**But nothing worked. However, If I use MYSQL instead of MS SQL, everything works like charm**

I am pasting some of Entities and Hibernate Configuration below

Base Entity Class Being Extended by Every Entity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6486192088436426369L;

protected Long id;

private UserInfo createdBy;
private Long createdById;
private Date creationDatetime;

private UserInfo lastModifiedBy;
private Long lastModifiedById;

private Date lastModifiedDatetime;

public AbstractEntity() {
}

public AbstractEntity(UserInfo createdBy, Date creationDatetime,
        UserInfo lastModifiedBy, Date lastModifiedDatetime) {
    super();
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.creationDatetime = creationDatetime;
    this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    this.lastModifiedDatetime = lastModifiedDatetime;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "createdById", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public UserInfo getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(UserInfo createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

@Column(name = "createdById", insertable = true, updatable = true)
public Long getCreatedById() {
    return createdById;
}

public void setCreatedById(Long createdById) {
    this.createdById = createdById;
}

public Date getCreationDatetime() {
    return creationDatetime;
}

public void setCreationDatetime(Date creationDatetime) {
    this.creationDatetime = creationDatetime;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "lastModifiedById", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public UserInfo getLastModifiedBy() {
    return lastModifiedBy;
}

public void setLastModifiedBy(UserInfo lastModifiedBy) {
    this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
}

@Column(name = "lastModifiedById", insertable = true, updatable = true)
public Long getLastModifiedById() {
    return lastModifiedById;
}

public void setLastModifiedById(Long lastModifiedById) {
    this.lastModifiedById = lastModifiedById;
}

public Date getLastModifiedDatetime() {
    return lastModifiedDatetime;
}

public void setLastModifiedDatetime(Date lastModifiedDatetime) {
    this.lastModifiedDatetime = lastModifiedDatetime;
}

}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
public class Company extends AbstractEntity{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8145899358902689000L;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

DAO Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DaoSQLConfiguration {

@Value("${jdbc.database.driver.class.name}")
public String DB_DRIVER;

@Value("${jdbc.database.url}")
public String DB_URL;

@Value("${jdbc.database.schema}")
public String DB_SCHEMA;

@Value("${jdbc.database.username}")
public String DB_USER;

@Value("${jdbc.database.password}")
public String DB_PASSWORD;

@Value("${jdbc.database.maxPoolSize}")
public int DB_MAX_POOL_SIZE;

@Value("${jdbc.database.minPoolSize}")
public int DB_MIN_POOL_SIZE;

@Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
public String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

@Value("${hibernate.show.sql}")
public String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

@Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
public String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

@Resource
private EntityInterceptor entityInterceptor;

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    hibernateTemplate.setCheckWriteOperations(false);
    return hibernateTemplate;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new ImprovedNamingStrategy());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.entities" });
    sessionFactoryBean.setEntityInterceptor(entityInterceptor);
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "com.hipzone.sam.dao.sql.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
    properties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");


    return properties;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {


    ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    comboPooledDataSource.setDriverClass(DB_DRIVER);
    comboPooledDataSource.setJdbcUrl(DB_URL + "/" + DB_SCHEMA);
    comboPooledDataSource.setUser(DB_USER);
    comboPooledDataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
    comboPooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(DB_MAX_POOL_SIZE);


    return comboPooledDataSource;

}

}
```

Config Properties

```
jdbc.database.driver.class.name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.database.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433
jdbc.database.schema=test
jdbc.database.username=sa
jdbc.database.password=
jdbc.database.maxPoolSize=5
jdbc.database.minPoolSize=1

#Hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.show.sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Complete Exception

```
Hibernate: alter table user_info add constraint FK7gdskowpafinvcqig7p419prj foreign key (created_by_id) references user_info
WARN  19-Mar-17 00:48:58 ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl:handleException:27 GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3831)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1349)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: There is already an object named 'FK7gdskowpafinvcqig7p419prj' in the database.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeImpl(JtdsStatement.java:809)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.execute(JtdsStatement.java:1282)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.execute(NewProxyStatement.java:1006)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 91 more
```

Comment: I have the same problem, which came up when upgrading to Hibernate 5 (it was working fine with version 4). Did you find a solution?

Comment: here there could be a provisional solution, I need to test it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10574

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your hibernate version to `5.4.3.Final` and This problem will be solved.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can find maven repository for hibernate 5.4.3.Final here: [Hibernate's core ORM Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.3.Final)

Comment: I have the same problem but I am using spring jpa. 
`<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>`